# Не могу использовать переменную которая ждет загрузки документа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два внешных скрипта

```
<script src="js/script1.js" defer"></script>
<script src="js/script2.js" defer"></script>
```

в `script1.js`  программа *ждет загрузки документа* и *присваивает* значение переменной  `x`.

```js
console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  let x;
  $( document ).ready( function () {
      x = 'set to global variable';
  });
</script>
```

в `script2.js`  показывается  глобальная  переменная  `x`.

Но это значение равна `undefined`.

Как в `script2.js` получить присвоенное значение переменной `x` а не `undefined` ?

Приблизительно понимаю почему так происходит, функцию setTimeout использовать не хочу.

Comment: в script2.js: `$( document ).ready( function () { показывается глобальная переменная  x  });`

Comment: Но правильно ли будет  использовать  $( document ).ready в script2.js . Это  правильный подход в таких случаях  и не приведет ли это к ошибке в  будущем  ?

Comment: использовать будет правильно

Comment: К ошибке не приведет. Обработчики `$(document).ready` выполняются (и будут выполняться в дальнейшем) в той последовательности, в какой были назначены.

Comment: могу ошибаться, но defer первое, что пришло в голову, без шаманизма с document.ready. 
Или я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в script1.js присвоение значения переменной `x` откладывается до события `$(document).ready`, то и в script2.js надо делать то же самое:

```
//в script2.js: 
$( document ).ready( function () { 
  //показывается глобальная переменная x 
});
```

Обработчики `$(document).ready` выполняются (и будут выполняться в дальнейшем) в той последовательности, в какой были назначены.

Answer (score 3):

Если в script1.js переменная внутри анонимной функции - то никак.
Если функция не анонимная - то доступ к переменной будет, иначе разместите результат переменной в какой-либо объект DOM дерева и в script2 вытащите это значение уже с объекта DOM.